# sqoop to transfer data to HDFS from Teradata

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, teradata, sqoop

sqoop to transfer data to HDFS from Teradata:
Getting error as below:
-bash-4.1$ sqoop import --connection-manager com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \

> --connect jdbc:teradata://dwsoat.dws.company.co.uk/DATABASE=TS_72258_BASELDB \
>   --username userid -P --table ADDRESS --num-mappers 3 \
>   --target-dir /user/nathalok/ADDRESS
>   Warning: /apps/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>   14/10/29 14:00:14 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4-cdh5.1.3
>   14/10/29 14:00:14 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
>   14/10/29 14:00:14 ERROR sqoop.ConnFactory: Sqoop wasn't able to create connnection manager properly. Some of the connectors supports explicit --driver and some do not. Please try to either specify --driver or leave it out.
>   14/10/29 14:00:14 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory.(java.lang.String, com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:165)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.init(ImportTool.java:84)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:494)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory.(java.lang.String, com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions)
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:151)
>           ... 9 more

-bash-4.1$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get Teradata working properly using a Cloudera distribution, you need to do the following:

1. Install the [Teradata JDBC jars](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver) in /var/lib/sqoop. For me these were terajdbc4.jar and tdgssconfig.jar.
2. Install either [Cloudera Connector Powered by Teradata](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/sqoop/teradata/1-2c5-powered-by-teradata.html) or the [Cloudera Connector for Teradata](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/sqoop/teradata/1-2c5-powered-by-teradata.html) installed somewhere on your filesystem (I prefer /var/lib/sqoop).
3. In /etc/sqoop/conf/managers.d/, create a file (of any name) and add `com.cloudera.connector.teradata.TeradataManagerFactory=<location of connector jar>`. For example, I have /etc/sqoop/conf/managers.d/teradata => `com.cloudera.connector.teradata.TeradataManagerFactory=/var/lib/sqoop/sqoop-connector-teradata-1.2c5.jar`.

There are different ways to install the [Teradata connector](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/connectors/latest/Teradata/Cloudera-Connector-for-Teradata/Cloudera-Connector-for-Teradata-User-Guide.html) as well. For example, it may be easier to use Cloudera Manager.

If you're still having trouble, try reaching out to the [sqoop mailing list](http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html).

Comment: 1. sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:teradata://net.dws.server.co.uk --username $user -password $pass                                                                                           2.sqoop import -libjars /home/path/tdgssconfig.jar,/home/path/terajdbc4.jar --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --connect "jdbc:teradata://server.co.uk/database=TS_75739"  -m 1 --username test --password pass1# --query "...."   Both this worked for me, only your server name should be reachable by DNS and it worked.